# Software to use webcam with multiple chat applications simultaneously

Tags: webcam

I'm currently experiencing issues with '**Many Cam**'. [As per Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ManyCam):

> Many Cam is a freeware program that allows users to have the ability to use their webcam with multiple chat applications simultaneously, such as **Skype**, **Omegle,** **Chatroulette**, **MSN**, or **YouTube**. Users can also add live CGI graphics inside any webcam application, such as changing the appearance of their face, eyes, hair, background and more. **ManyCam Pro** is a paid upgrade, it provides users with a professional quality live video production studio.”

Unfortunately, though, and as clever as the software is, you're left very much on your own as to the setup and a lot depends on what O/S your using and occasionally the browser setting.

The issues I refer to are simply that when I shift from Skype, for example to YouTube, the Many Cam driver refuses to change to the new location (Many Cam installs only one driver for the software to operate) with the result that I need to reboot my PC, and then make the transition.

Is there a similar software that gives better control and seamless switching between applications?

Comment: Most people don't know Manycams. Please write your question as if nobody knew Manycams. In particular, please list all of the features you expect the software to have.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Another hint: We are not the place for "help me *fix* this software", but for "help me *find* this software; so whilest you [edit] your post, I'd recommend to remove that part. Also check & fix your tags.

Comment: If you're having trouble with your account, see http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Good rephrasing, Flyk – at least it's clear now what *functionality* the OP is after. // **James:** you should include for which OS you'll need that, though – then I'd say the question could be re-opened to permit answers.

Comment: For what operating system? Windows?

Comment: I would assume Windows from the mention of 'PC' in the question, but it would be nice to have it specifically stated